Smartmontool's drivedb.h seems to contain non-documented entries
For a tool I'm writing (not using C language) I wrote a parser for drivedb.h from the description, not from the source code.
However I found some entries where no documentation exists.
Some questions:

What is the meaning of "HDD" in (e.g.) -v 6,raw48,Read_Channel_Margin,HDD?
Documentation says "-v ID,FORMAT[:BYTEORDER][,NAME],"
What is the use of entries without a NAME, e.g. in "-v 188,raw16 -v 240,msec24hour32"?
Contrary to the syntax shown it seems that "FORMAT[:BYTEORDER]" is optional; at least that's what I assume when  -v 192,emergencyretractcyclect is valid.
However, shouldn't there be two commata then?
If not it's hard to tell whether the "second" field is "FORMAT[:BYTEORDER]" or "NAME".
There are two pseudo entries, both using - as regular expression for "modelregexp" and "firmwareregexp": A "metadata header" and the "DEFAULT" entry.
How would matching the DEFAULT entry be done?
Via the "modelfamily", or via position (2nd) in the list (obviously matching - would result in at least unwanted entry)?

The version I'm working with is somewhat older smartmontools-6.6 and $Id: drivedb.h 4591 2017-11-04 22:40:53Z chrfranke $ (just in case).
